# Getting error on return result for async Task<dynamic>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling an API and successfully getting the result. I also convert the result to and object called "ResultCgOrder"

The problem is, when I return the result and catch it in to my controller it give the error

My code:

```
public async Task<dynamic> createOrder(CgOrder data){
        ResultCgOrder resultCgOrder = new ResultCgOrder();
        string path = "https://XXX/orders";

        ApiHeaderGet(createHashString());

        var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("order_id", data.OrderId.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("price", data.Price.ToString()),               
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("success_url", data.SuccessUrl)
        }
            );

        var response = await client.PostAsync(path, body);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
            resultCgOrder = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResultCgOrder>();
        }

        return  resultCgOrder;
    }
```

Now I am calling this by using following code;

```
APIHelper apiCall = new APIHelper ();
ResultCgOrder resultOrder = apiCall.createOrder(CgOrder);
```

The last line showing the error -- Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task dynamic' to 'xxx.Code.ResultCgOrder'--
error screen shot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILmbR.png)

Comment: you need `await` before the function call.

Comment: ResultCgOrder resultOrder = await apiCall.createOrder(CgOrder);

Comment: you can try `apiCall.createOrder(CgOrder).Result;`

Comment: @johnny after adding, showing different error 
Error 257 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<WS.Common.JoinResponse>'.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal No, do not recommend blocking on async calls.

Comment: @Sam, You can `await` only within `async` method? Or you can ask for `Result` but that will explicitly block the execution flow until results are there (which is kind a evil especially on UI)... Btw can the return value be Task<ResultCgOrder>?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal after adding .Result, the error gone but code execution is not getting any data. any Idea? infact it block the execution as Jonny said.

Comment: @Sam you probably have a deadlock. There is no reason for you to use `.Result` based on the code you have shown. You can await everything.

Comment: Why "dynamic" ? You know it will be a ResultCgOrder ...

Comment: @Crowcoder, in such a case what is your suggestion based on existing code.

Comment: @Sam The suggestion is not to use `Result`.  You need to `await` an asynchronous operation when you want to use its result.

Comment: @Servy using result is not working and it actually stop the execution of code. but i used await and it show error and code not building. the error is :
Error 257 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<xx.Common.JoinResponse>'.

Comment: @Sam So did you do what the error message told you to do to fix the problem?

Comment: @servy, well Servy, u see, i had to make the call async to sync by using .Result and while i call i use var. thus make the error gone.

Comment: @Sam If you need to do your work asynchronously then you shouldn't have written an `async` method that does a bunch of work asynchronously, you should have written it synchronously (or figured out how to make the caller asynchronous, if this work really needs to be done asynchronously).

Answer (score -1):

This is how i made it work:

```
public async Task<ResultCgOrder> createOrder(CgOrder data)
    {
        ResultCgOrder resultCgOrder = new ResultCgOrder();
        string path = "https://api-xxx";

        nonce = Convert.ToString(Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
        ApiHeaderGet(createHashString());

        var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("order_id", data.OrderId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("price", data.Price.ToString()),               
        }
            );

        var incomingResult =  client.PostAsync(path, body).Result;
        if (incomingResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            resultCgOrder = await incomingResult.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResultCgOrder>();
        }

        return resultCgOrder;
    }
```

And i called it the following way:

```
 var resultCgOrder =  apiCall.createOrder(CgOrder);               
 string newString = resultCgOrder.Result.price;
```